# While uploading to App Store the upload failed ERROR ITMS-90081

Tags: swift, app-store, xcode10

When I upload the build in App Store I get this message: `ERROR ITMS-90081: "This bundle is invalid. Applications built for more than one architecture require an iOS Deployment Target of 3.0 or later."`

In my project I am using Xcode 10 with swift 4.2. In my pods file I have put watchos plateform to 4.0 and I am using Alamofire version as pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'.

Does Alamofire support watch os 4.0 ?

Please help..

Comment: I had the same error, but I'm using Swift PM. It was caused by Firebase. Still don't know how to heal, just deleted the package.

Comment: Resolved! I was need to remove all auxilary Firebase products I added. Removed Crashlytics. And now I'm able to upload.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering a work around here so that build upload doesn't stop at App Store.
For this problem until Alamofire provide an update for watchOS 4 you can **Manually update the target for pods that you are using your project**.

For reference this is what I got when someone posted for a similar problem:
[Can't upload App using Alamofire on watchOS when using Xcode 10](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2606)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have this error with Firebase.

I was using Swift PM and got the same error, and also other errors like:

> ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format..."
> ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value..."
> ITMS-90124: "The binary is invalid..."

and other.

It was totally unobvious. I added many Firebase sublibraries (products) like `FirebaseCrashlytics`, which were actually not very necessary in my project. Removed them, keeping only the `FirebaseAnalytics`, and everything worked well.

**So if you have this error and whatever package I would recommend removing/adding products.**